# Options not appending to select

Tags: jquery

```
$(document).ready(function(){
  $( "#upl" ).delay(400).slideDown(1000,function(){$('select').material_select();});
  $('select[name=department]').change(function(){
    dept = $(this).val();
    request_url = '/get_sub_list/' + dept + '/';
    $.ajax({
      url: request_url,
      type: 'GET',
      dataType:'json',
      success: function(data){
        $.each(data, function(index, text){
          console.log(text.pk+"|"+text.fields.subject_code+"|"+text.fields.subject_name);
            $('select[name=subject]').empty().append("<option></option>").val(text.pk).html(text.fields.subject_code+"|"+text.fields.subject_name);
          });
        }
      });});
    });
```

So I am getting a proper output in the console, but stuff is not being appended to the select. I am a newbie to this, so please if anyone could help me.

Comment: $('select[name=subject]option').empty().append("<option value="+text.pk+">"+text.fields.subject_code+"|"+text.fields.subject_name+</option>");

Comment: is there any error in your console

Comment: try my answer @vipul Ujawane

Comment: Thanks a lot for all your help, turns out it was a problem due to Materialize CSS framework which I was using.

Answer (score 0):

try this :

```
$('select[name=subject]').empty();
    $.ajax({
        url: request_url,
        type: 'GET',
        dataType:'json',
        success: function(data){
            $.each(data, function(index, text){
                console.log(text.pk+"|"+text.fields.subject_code+"|"+text.fields.subject_name);
                $('select[name=subject]').append($('<option></option>').val(text.pk).html(text.fields.subject_code+"|"+text.fields.subject_name));
            });
        }
     });
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this,

```
  $('select[name=subject]').empty().append("<option>"+text.fields.subject_code+"|"+text.fields.subject_name +"</option>").val(text.pk);
```

Answer (score 0):

$('select[name=subject]').empty().append(""+text.fields.subject_code+"|"+text.fields.subject_name +"").val(text.pk);

Answer (score 0):

1) problem is your option  empty() is inside the each loop. so each time  of appending the previously appended options are removed .

2) so empty should be outside of each loop like this

```
$('select[name=subject]').empty();
$.each(data, function(index, text){

  $('select[name=subject]').append("<option></option>").val(text.pk).html(text.fields.subject_code+"|"+text.fields.subject_name);

 // (or)

  $('select[name=subject]option').append("<option value='"+text.pk+"'>"+text.fields.subject_code+"|"+text.fields‌​.subject_name+"</opti‌​on>");

}
```